# Set subfolder as index website

Tags: html, .htaccess

i am developing new website with 2 language (English & Indonesian) with bootstrap, PHP and MySQL. i put english website files in "en" folder and indonesian website files in "in" folder. I want to set the default page of my website to /in . so when i access my website `www.mydomainname.com` it will automatically redirected to `www.mydomainname.com/in` . How do i do this? maybe you guys could help. Thanks a lot

Here is my website folders look a like :

```
/mydomainname
/mydomainname/in
/mydomainname/en
```

Comment: Show us what you try.

Comment: it's solved. i fill .htaccess in root folder with RedirectMatch ^/$ /en
and put another .htaccess in subfolder with DirectoryIndex index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DirectroryIndex` directive in `.htaccess`

```
DirectoryIndex en
```

This will rewrite  `http://example.com/` to `example.com/en` without changing the url.

You can also use `RedirectMatch` to redirect your homepage `/` to the `/en` . changing your browser url from `/` to `/en` .

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /en
```

References :

DirectoryIndex  (mod-dir)

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html

RedirectMatch  (mod-alias)

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: yay! it's works perfectly. i create .htaccess in root folder with RedirectMatch ^/$ /en and create another one in /en folder with DirectoryIndex index.php . thanks man!